# Labeling successive equations with the same number and different superscripts

Tags: numbering, labels, tag

This question is related to 
[this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357979/make-a-subscript-in-the-label-of-an-equation) but is not a duplicate of it.

I'd like to label my first equation as (1^+)   and my third equation as (1^-).     The first part is easy, but if I `\label` that first equation, then try to use the label inside a `\tag` when I number the third equation, my third equation label is  (1^{+-}) which of course I don't want.   So I need to be able to save the number part of the first equation, without its superscript, then include that saved number in the `\tag` for the third equation.     Here's an MWE of what goes wrong.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\refstepcounter{equation}
\tag{\theequation$\empty^+$}
\label{label}
f^+   = 3 \\
g     = 4 \\
\tag{\ref{label}$\empty^-$}
f^-   = -3 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is probably cheating, since it uses a plain tex command ...

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{1}
\xdef\plusminuseq{\number\theequation}
\begin{align}
\tag{\plusminuseq$^{+}$}
\label{label1}
f^+   = 3 \\
g     = 4 \\
\tag{\plusminuseq$^{-}$}
\label{label2}
f^-   = -3 
\end{align}
now, references to \eqref{label1} and \eqref{label2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the `\xdef` is needed to "freeze" the value of `\theequation`.  (there's most likely an equivalent latex command to do this, but i don't remember, and don't have time to look it up.)

Comment: Call it "core TeX".

Comment: I accepted @barbara_beeton's answer because it's more general.   Dont see why on earth it would be considered cheating to use core TeX.   If anybody else is interested, I made it general with `\newcommand{\saveEqNum}[1]{
    \xdef\saveEqNumXdef{\number\theequation}
    \newcommand{#1}{\saveEqNumXdef}
    }` so now I can put `\saveEqNum{\thisEquationNum}` anywhere in the document

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}

\newcommand{\myformat}[1]% #1 = counter name
{\ifcase\value{#1}\or-\or\or+\else\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{$\theparentequation^{\myformat{equation}}$}
\begin{align}
f^+   &= 3 \\
g     &= 4 \\
f^-   &= -3 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]