# Labels and tags with parametric dependence

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, labels, tags

Suppose there is an equation with a parameter, and the parameter is represented in equation's tag:

[image]

I'm looking for a way how to refer to this equation using two different `\lambda`, say, `\lambda_1` and `\lambda_2`.
It is possible to write

[image]

But I would like to write it in a shorter form

[image]

in such a way that `$(E_{\lambda_1})$` and `$(E_{\lambda_2})$` refer to the equation, as in the variant above.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \label{1}
    \tag{$E_\lambda$}
    -u'' = \lambda u.
    \end{equation}

    It is possible to write: Consider \eqref{1} with $\lambda=\lambda_1$ and $\lambda=\lambda_2$.

    But I would like to write: Consider $(E_{\lambda_1})$ and $(E_{\lambda_2})$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: with your referencing i will look for two equations: `E_{\lambda_1}` and `E_{\lambda_1}`, but you have only one tagged with `\lambda_1` ... don't do this, you will only make a mess in your document.

Comment: @Zarko In variety of situations such way provides a simplification for the reader without causing any mess. In fact, in my real text, there is only one equation (main one), at the very beginning of the text, tagged like `E_\lambda`. All other equations have usual numbering. It would be very convenient to refer to this equation with different `\lambda`'s. (In my case, it is as clear as to vary a subindex in the definition of some function, i.e., `f_{n_1}`, `f_{n_2}`, etc.)

Comment: sorry, i disagree with you. however, some one can provide solution which you like to have. technically this is possible. but i will not do this.

Answer (score 3):

One possible simple solution which fits me is based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357989/49138) and looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareRobustCommand\lambind{\lambda}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \label{1}
    \tag{$E_{\lambind}$}
    -u'' = \lambda u.
    \end{equation}

    It is possible to write: Consider \eqref{1} with $\lambda=\lambda_1$ and $\lambda=\lambda_2$.

    But I would like to write: Consider {\renewcommand\lambind{\lambda_1}\eqref{1}} and {\renewcommand\lambind{\lambda_2}\eqref{1}}.
\end{document}
```

[image]